# Too many indices in numpy array when calculating size

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

```
def reg_interval_size(self, prediction, y, significance):
    idx = int(significance * 100 - 1)
    prediction = prediction[:, idx]
    
    prediction_size = prediction[:, 1] - prediction[:, 0]
    
    return prediction_size
```

This is the error I am getting when applying the function:

```
IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2
```

**My prediction interval**

```
[[-0.08654671  0.7144939 ]
 [-0.61418434  0.18685626]
 [ 0.16648421  0.96752482]
 ...
 [ 0.01177342  0.81281403]
 [ 0.44408509  1.2451257 ]
 [ 0.37012494  1.17116555]]
```

## Example

```
prediction_size = reg_interval_size(self, prediction, y, significance= 0.05):
```

**Expected Output**
(It is just a 1D array that calculates the difference in size between each row of the prediction interval array)

```
[0.80104061 0.80104061 0.80104061 ... 0.80104061 0.80104061 0.80104061]
```

Comment: Isn't it because you have 2d array and trying to index it with 3 indices? So you want `prediction[idx]` or `prediction[:,idx]` (or completely different thing)

Comment: If you'd share a small example and expected result, that would be helpful.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych hey thanks for the pointer, I have updated it accordingly but now get a new error. Still new to numpy :D

Comment: With that `significance`, `idx` is 4, `int(0.05*100-1)`.  That doesn't work if `predicition` only has 2 columns.

Comment: @hpaulj yes you are completely right, didn't notice this. Was wondering if it would be possible to set it to a way that each time I were to change the value of significance, to not get an indexing error

Comment: I don't understand what `significance` is supposed to be doing.

Comment: @hpaulj it's just a threshold value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`idx` is an `int` so `idx[0]` makes no sense.

`prediction` is a 2d array so **you can't** access it with 3 indices like this:

```py
prediction = prediction[:, :, idx] # error
```

I don't know what you want to do but **you can** do this:

```py
prediction = prediction[:, idx]
```

Comment: I was able to update the question accordingly but now get a new error.  I'm still trying to figure out numpy accordingly.

Comment: sorry you are right, just did. The only thing was that I updated the code you just suggested. now I'm getting another index error as seen in the question.